# TensorFlow memory use while running on GPU: why does it look like not all memory is used?

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, memory-management, deep-learning

This is a follow-up to my question posted here: [Memory error with larger images when running convolutional neural network using TensorFlow on AWS instance g2.2xlarge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436633/memory-error-with-larger-images-when-running-convolutional-neural-network-using/48438660#48438660)

I built a CNN model in Python using TensorFlow and run it on NVIDIA GRID K520 GPU. It runs fine with 64x64 images, but produces a memory error with 128x128 images (even when input consists of only 1 image).

The error says `Ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.00GiB.` 2GiB is the size of my first fully-connected layer (input: `128*128*2(channels)` output: `128*128 * 4 bytes = 2.14748 GB = 2.0 GiB`).

From [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cloud-gaming-gpu-boards.html), I can see that GRID K520 has 8GB = 7.45GiB memory. When I start running my code, I also see the output: `Total memory: 3.94GiB, Free memory: 3.91GiB`.

My question is, what is the relationship between all these numbers: if there are 7.45GiB of memory on GPU, why there are only 3.94GiB of total memory and most importantly, why GPU cannot allocate 2GiB memory, which is just above half of total memory? (I am not a computer scientist, so a detailed answer would be valuable.)

Some more specific information in case it is useful:
I tried using `allow_growth` and `per_process_gpu_memory_fraction`. Still get the memory error, but also some memory stats (would really appreciate if someone could explain to me these numbers):

```
allow_growth = True
Stats: 
Limit:                  3878682624
InUse:                  2148557312
MaxInUse:               2148557312
NumAllocs:                      13
MaxAllocSize:           2147483648

allow_growth = False
Stats: 
Limit:                  3878682624
InUse:                  3878682624
MaxInUse:               3878682624
NumAllocs:                      13
MaxAllocSize:           3877822976

per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.5
allow_growth = False
Stats: 
Limit:                  2116026368
InUse:                      859648
MaxInUse:                   859648
NumAllocs:                      12
MaxAllocSize:               409600

per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.5
allow_growth = True
Stats: 
Limit:                  2116026368
InUse:                     1073664
MaxInUse:                  1073664
NumAllocs:                      12
MaxAllocSize:               623616
```

Minimal working example: with dummy training set of the same size as the images I input and only one fully-connected layer (full model code is [here](https://github.com/tetianadadakova/MRI-CNN/blob/master/myAutomap.py)). This example works with input of size:

```
X_train = np.random.rand(1, 64, 64, 2)
Y_train = np.random.rand(1, 64, 64)
```

but doesn't work with input of size

```
X_train = np.random.rand(1, 128, 128, 2)
Y_train = np.random.rand(1, 128, 128)
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


# Dummy training set:
X_train = np.random.rand(1, 128, 128, 2)
Y_train = np.random.rand(1, 128, 128)
print('X_train.shape at input = ', X_train.shape, ", Size = ",
      X_train.shape[0] * X_train.shape[1] * X_train.shape[2]
      * X_train.shape[3])
print('Y_train.shape at input = ', Y_train.shape, ", Size = ",
      Y_train.shape[0] * Y_train.shape[1] * Y_train.shape[2])


def create_placeholders(n_H0, n_W0):

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_H0, n_W0, 2], name='x')
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, n_H0, n_W0], name='y')

    return x, y


def forward_propagation(x):

    x_temp = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(x)  # size (n_im, n_H0 * n_W0 * 2)
    n_out = np.int(x.shape[1] * x.shape[2])  # size (n_im, n_H0 * n_W0)

    # FC: input size (n_im, n_H0 * n_W0 * 2), output size (n_im, n_H0 * n_W0)
    FC1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
        x_temp,
        n_out,
        activation_fn=tf.tanh,
        normalizer_fn=None,
        normalizer_params=None,
        weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(),
        weights_regularizer=None,
        biases_initializer=None,
        biases_regularizer=None,
        reuse=True,
        variables_collections=None,
        outputs_collections=None,
        trainable=True,
        scope='fc1')

    # Reshape output from FC layer into array of size (n_im, n_H0, n_W0, 1):
    FC_M = tf.reshape(FC1, [tf.shape(x)[0], tf.shape(x)[1], tf.shape(x)[2], 1])

    return FC_M


def compute_cost(FC_M, Y):

    cost = tf.square(FC_M - Y)

    return cost


def model(X_train, Y_train, learning_rate=0.0001, num_epochs=100):

    (m, n_H0, n_W0, _) = X_train.shape

    # Create Placeholders
    X, Y = create_placeholders(n_H0, n_W0)

    # Build the forward propagation
    DECONV = forward_propagation(X)

    # Add cost function to tf graph
    cost = compute_cost(DECONV, Y)

    # Backpropagation
    optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    # Initialize all the variables globally
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    # Memory config
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True

    # Start the session to compute the tf graph
    with tf.Session(config = config) as sess:

        # Initialization
        sess.run(init)

        # Training loop
        for epoch in range(num_epochs):

            _, temp_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost],
                                    feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: Y_train})

            print ('EPOCH = ', epoch, 'COST = ', np.mean(temp_cost))


# Finally run the model
model(X_train, Y_train, learning_rate=0.00002, num_epochs=5)
```

Traceback:

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:274] ****************************************************************************************************
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:275] Ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.00GiB.  See logs for memory state.
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:983] Internal: Dst tensor is not initialized.
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:594] Executor failed to create kernel. Internal: Dst tensor is not initialized.
     [[Node: zeros = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [32768,16384] values: [0 0 0]...>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myAutomap_MinExample.py", line 99, in <module>
    num_epochs=5)
  File "myAutomap_MinExample.py", line 85, in model
    sess.run(init)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Dst tensor is not initialized.
     [[Node: zeros = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [32768,16384] values: [0 0 0]...>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'zeros', defined at:
  File "myAutomap_MinExample.py", line 99, in <module>
    num_epochs=5)
  File "myAutomap_MinExample.py", line 72, in model
    optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 289, in minimize
    name=name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 403, in apply_gradients
    self._create_slots(var_list)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/rmsprop.py", line 103, in _create_slots
    self._zeros_slot(v, "momentum", self._name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py", line 647, in _zeros_slot
    named_slots[var] = slot_creator.create_zeros_slot(var, op_name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/slot_creator.py", line 121, in create_zeros_slot
    val = array_ops.zeros(primary.get_shape().as_list(), dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1352, in zeros
    output = constant(zero, shape=shape, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 103, in constant
    attrs={"value": tensor_value, "dtype": dtype_value}, name=name).outputs[0]
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2327, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1226, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InternalError (see above for traceback): Dst tensor is not initialized.
     [[Node: zeros = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [32768,16384] values: [0 0 0]...>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

Comment: Additional information: I run the model at p3.2xlarge AWS instance (NVIDIA Tesla V100, 16 GiB) today. The minimal example, which has only one fully connected layer, runs without errors. The model, which has two fully-connected layers, stops with OOM error at the second fully-connected layer, which has shape[16384,16384].

Answer (score 3):

It would be good, if you can upload your code or at least a minimal example in order to see what is going on. Just looking at these numbers, it seems `allow_growth` is working as it should, that is, it is only allocating the amount of memory that it actually needs (the 2.148 GiB you calculated above).

Also can you provide the full console output of the error you are getting. 
My guess is, that you are confusing a non fatal warning message from the TF resource allocator for the actual error that's causing your program to fail.

Is this similar to the message that you are seeing?

`W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:217] Allocator (GPU_1_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.55GiB. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory is available.`

Because this is just a warning that you may ignore unless you want to optimize the runtime performance of your code. It is not something that will cause your program to fail.

Comment: I edited my question: added the minimal working example and a link to full code, as well as full error message. Thank you Max F for helping.

Comment: I will try to run your code next week. But it does not seem to be a problem with the memory size.
First advice, don't use the numpy type casting in `forward_propagation` (stick with tensorflow). 

And try `init = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())` as the problem seems to be with some uninitialized tensor.

Comment: I tried using init, which you suggested, and removing the numpy casting, however, still got the same error.

Comment: I tried to run your code, but get a different error:
`ValueError: Variable fc1/weights does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?`
Set reuse to False, then I get the OOM error.
But you are also creating a fully connected layer with `128 + 128 = 16384` output (or hidden) neurons which is pretty huge

Comment: For semantic segmentation, which I assume you are aiming at, you should use convolutional layers and work with cross-entropy loss

Comment: Thank you for running my code, `reuse` parameter is set differently depending on the TF version. I am trying to reproduce the results in this paper (they do not publish their code, but they say that they use TensorFlow as well) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.08841.pdf. See Fig 1c for the network - first two layers are fully connected followed by convolutional. This is used for the medical image reconstruction from frequency space. In the paper, the authors use a very expensive GPU, I am aiming for a cheaper one, but I cannot choose which one I should use before I know why I get the memory error.

Comment: Max, which GPU do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Looking the error log it looks like or you are running out of GPU memory or the tensor is not initiated at that point. You can try to insert Tensor::IsInitialized before the line that start the problem (99) to make sure it's the GPU, if it is, you may have some code still running in the GPU, from previous tries, make sure that is not happening.
There is two discussions that I think may be relevant for your problem, here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7025 and here: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/issues/38
Good luck